# CentOS VPS not starting after installing zPanel

Tags: centos, software-installation, startup

I've had some trouble earlier installing zPanel, but then I was told that I've been using the wrong package, I was supposed to use the 32-bit version, but kept trying with 64-bit. After figuring that, I've immediately re-installed my system (CentOS 6.4 32-bit) and started installing zPanel.

Everything went fine and the installation finished and gave me these details in the end:

```
# MySQL Root Password    : XXXX
# MySQL Postfix Password : XXXX
# ZPanelX Username       : zadmin                     
# ZPanelX Password       : XXXX
```

All good, except that my system is not starting up anymore! It simply wont boot up after the auto-reboot by zPanel.

In SolusVM, the VPS is showing as online, but nothing's working. I can't access my IP via browser, can't access my IP via SSH (PuTTY) and same applies to SFTP with Filezilla - it's simply dead!

I tried rebooting, booting, shutting down... everything!

This is the guide I was following: http://www.zvps.co.uk/zpanelcp/centos-6

I would really appreciate some help.